# pandas: combine columns if they share a partly similar name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sent_a.1': [0, 3, 2, 1],
               'sent_a.2': [0, 1, 4, 0],
               'sent_b.3': [0, 6, 0, 8],
               'sent_b.4': [1, 1, 8, 6]
               })
```

I want to combine the columns that share a name. so the desired output would be,

```
    sent_a  sent_b  
0     0,0    0,1
1     3,1    6,1
2     2,4    0,8 
3     1,0    8,6
```

I have done the following and the code works, but since my original DataFrame has more than 200 columns, I am looking for a faster way of doing that.

```
df['sent_a'] = df['sent_a.1']+','+ df['sent_a.2']
df['sent_b'] = df['sent_b.1']+','+ df['sent_b.2']
df = df.drop(['sent_a.1', 'sent_a.2', 'sent_b.3', 'sent_b.4'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` on the columns using the left part of the column names as group:

```
# get left part of name
group = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]

# groupby and join as string
(df.astype(str).groupby(group, axis=1)
   .apply(lambda d: d.apply(','.join, axis=1))
)
```

output:

```
  sent_a sent_b
0    0,0    0,1
1    3,1    6,1
2    2,4    0,8
3    1,0    8,6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the columns MultiIndex and `unstack` and `groupby` the index and apply `join` to get a Series similar to the desired outcome. `swaplevel` + `unstack` will fetch the desired DataFrame.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col.split('.') for col in df.columns)
out = df.unstack().astype(str).droplevel(1).groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(','.join).swaplevel().unstack()
```

Output:

```
  sent_a sent_b
0    0,0    0,1
1    3,1    6,1
2    2,4    0,8
3    1,0    8,6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby the first part of the columns names, with `axis=1` (to group column-wise instead of row-wise), and for each group, use the built-in `functools.reduce` to join all the columns together:

```
import functools as ft
new_df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).apply(lambda g: ft.reduce(lambda x, y: x + ',' + y, [x[col].astype(str) for col in x]))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  sent_a sent_b
0    0,0    0,0
1    3,1    3,1
2    2,4    2,4
3    1,0    1,0
```